# jQuery - Load image into div from dynamic URL

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to load an image into a div once a URL has been populated into an input box.

So far I have managed to get an alert to display once the input div has been populated..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery( ".mediafield-url" ).change(function() {
        alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Now I want to replace this alert and instead have the image display in a div pulled from the URL.

Anyone point me in the direction of an example or some reading on the jquery function I need to be looking at to achieve it?

UPDATE

Following on from the update by Newt I now have this..

```
function custom_admin_js() {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(\'.mediafield-url\').change(function(){
    var a = $(this).val();
    var new_img = \'<img src=\'+a+\'>\';
    jQuery(\'.your-div\').html(new_img);
});
    </script>';
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'custom_admin_js');
```

This is triggering in the admin section of WordPress, although it works fine in the JSFiddle, when run in the WP admin section it gives me the error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function post-new.php?post_type=image:716
(anonymous function) post-new.php?post_type=image:716

n.event.dispatch load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,json2&ver=3.9.2:3
r.handle load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,json2&ver=3.9.2:3
n.event.trigger load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,json2&ver=3.9.2:3
e.event.trigger load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,json2&ver=3.9.2:8
(anonymous function) load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,json2&ver=3.9.2:3
n.extend.each load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,json2&ver=3.9.2:2
n.fn.n.each load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,json2&ver=3.9.2:2
n.fn.extend.trigger load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,json2&ver=3.9.2:3
send_to_editor post-new.php?post_type=image:754
(anonymous function) media-upload.php?type=file&tab=library&post_id=93:4
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is `.mediafield-url` the input box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve the problem:

```
$('.mediafield-url').change(function(){
    var a = $(this).val();
    var new_img = '<img src='+a+'>';
    $('.your-div').html(new_img);
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/v0ycp7a6/2/

Comment: Thanks for this, works great in the fiddle but not when implemented on site.  I have updated the original post...

Comment: Which line of the added code is the error being displayed in?

Comment: I am struggling to work out exactly where it is finding the problem.  I have added the full error from the console above

Comment: Ignore me, solved it!  WordPress didn't like the $ being used.  Changed it to jQuery and all is now working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you know the url of the image then just add a css attribute "background-url" to your div, for example like this:

```
$('yourDiv').css('background-image', 'url(http://yourUrl.de/image.jpg)').
```

Your browser should be able to load the image and place it as background image.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem as the url is unknown.

Comment: If the user inserts the url in the input he DOES know it by reading the value of the input. Didn't wrote how to get the inputs value because I guess that should be already known.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. But using `background-image` will need OP to specify a height and width to the div which is not possible based on the random dimensions of any URL that might be entered. To make it clearer, here's your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Newtt/8w7k4ffk/